# How To Register RouteConstraints in MVC6

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-web-api-routing

There are numerous tutorials on how to create RouteConstraints in previous MVC versions:

- [Registering ASP.NET MVC Route Constraints for Attribute Routing](http://www.khalidabuhakmeh.com/registering-asp-net-mvc-route-constraints-for-attribute-routing)
- [Constraints in Attribute-based Routing MVC5](http://mannpandey.blogspot.co.za/)

How does this work with MVC6, specifically registering the custom route constraint, so it can be used in attributes of ApiController Actions?

I have created a custom route constraint, called NonEmptyGuid, which really just makes sure a non-empty Guid is used as the parameter of a **GET** Action:

```
public class NonEmptyGuid : IRouteConstraint
{
    public bool Match(HttpContext httpContext, IRouter route, string routeKey, IDictionary<string, object> values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        if (!values.ContainsKey(routeKey)) return false;

        if (values[routeKey].ToString().Equals(Guid.Empty.ToString())) return false;

        return true;
    }
}
```

**Question:**
How and where does one register this custom RouteConstraint for an **MVC6** application (e.g. in this case in a WebApi Project).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RouteOptions` to register your constraints:

```
services.Configure<RouteOptions>(options =>
                                options
                                .ConstraintMap
                                .Add("test", typeof(TestRouteConstraint)));
```