# Add new route constraint in .net5/vNext/MVC6

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In .NET 4.5 / WebApi 2, i could create a constraint and add it using this code

```
// add constraint resolvers
var constraintResolver = new DefaultInlineConstraintResolver();
constraintResolver.ConstraintMap.Add("constraintName", typeof(MyCustomConstraint));

// routing
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(constraintResolver);
```

Currently in my Startup.cs file, i just have this

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        // Enable Mvc for controllers
        app.UseMvc();

        // Enable all static file middleware (serving of static files and default files) EXCEPT directory browsing.
        app.UseFileServer();
    }
```

But i cannot figure out where to do this i asp.net 5/vNext. Can someone please help?  I am using attribute routing on all my controllers

Comment: perhaps you will find this article useful http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2015/02/07/asp-net-5-deep-dive-routing

Comment: Also this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32583743/how-to-register-routeconstraints-in-mvc6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can register in the ConfigureServices section of the Startup class.

```
    public virtual IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.Configure<RouteOptions>(options =>
                                        options
                                        .ConstraintMap
                                        .Add("constraintName", typeof(MyCustomConstraint)));
    }
```